# filter elements from habtm relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, rails-models

i have the following models:

```
class HealthCareInsurance < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :health_care_insurances
end
```

Now, inside my controller, i need to get only those filling the condition: "id NOT IN ( my_array )". Seems easy but i just cant make it work.

Im doing the following:

```
@company.health_care_insurances( :conditions => [ "id NOT IN ( ? )", insurances_array])
```

But for some reason it gives me the exact same elements as if i change the "NOT IN" condition for an "IN" condition. Tried "where" too, but it always returns an empty array. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC in SQL you need `id NOT IN  (?)` but dependent on your rails version I'd do it using active record.  What version of rails are you running?

Comment: Hi @japed. It's rails 4. And sorry i mistaken when i wrote the code, but the results i got were actually using the code you described: NOT IN (?)

Comment: What is in `insurances_array`?

Comment: ["276","279",..] . Basically what i get from params[:health_care_insurance_ids], that comes from here:                   <input id="health_care_insurance_<%= hc_insurance.id %>" name="health_care_insurance_ids[]" value="<%= hc_insurance.id %>" type="checkbox" >

Comment: Does the company actually have any `HealthCareInsurance` instances that aren't in those ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with Rails 4

```
@company.health_care_insurances.where.not(id: insurances_array)
```

Comment: Thanks @japed but nop, returns always nil.

Comment: Sorry @japed, my mistake. This is actually working. Thanks man.